# Eye gaze data at a fixed rate using Holographic Remoting

Tags: unity-game-engine, uwp, hololens, mrtk

I'm trying to obtain the eye tracking data at a fixed frame rate (30 Hz, as provided by the eye tracker in HoloLens2) and not tied to the `Update()` function of Unity because the rendering frame rate of my application is not stable. It seems that if I use `EyeGazeProvider`, some gaze samples are missed because it outputs the gaze data not at a fixed rate but depending on the rendering frame rate, even though I check for new gaze data asynchronously (every 10ms) using a timer. Using `Windows.UI.Input.Spatial.SpatialPointerPose` I could get the gaze samples at a fixed rate on a deployed HL2 app but I need to use the Remoting due to high rendering load of my scene.

However, I'm a bit confused about the usage of UWP APIs in Holographic Remoting (in play mode or standalone app) for HoloLens 2. Is it possible to use the class  `SpatialPointerPose` to obtain the eye tracking data with Remoting? Or is it mandatory to use the MRTK interface `EyeGazeProvider`, for the case of a non-UWP app (editor or standalone) as in the case of holographic remoting?

Comment: Do you want to know if UWP code will work while using play mode in Unity Editor with Holographic Remoting?

Comment: I want to know how to get the eye tracker data independent of the rendering frame rate. It seems to be only possible with the UWP code. Does it work with Holographic Remoting?

Comment: I checked the OpenXR Unity example [FollowEyeGaze.cs](https://github.com/microsoft/OpenXR-Unity-MixedReality-Samples/blob/bbbaf46701fab322df790bc092c029ed38a7e6d0/BasicSample/Assets/Interaction/Scripts/FollowEyeGaze.cs). Here the code to retrieve the gaze data is written in the `Update` which means that it will be synced to the frame rate i.e. called every frame. This means that if the frame rate drop below 30 Hz, which is the HL2 eye tracker frequency, gaze samples will be missed. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Your understanding is right. If you'd like to get the gaze data at a fixed rate, you may try with `FixedUpdate()` instead of `Update()`.

Comment: Tried it but still got the same result. It seems that eye tracking is inherently tied to the rendering rate for some reason.

Comment: How about using a timer as you've tried? Just use `eyeTrackingDevice.TryGetFeatureValue` instead of `Windows.UI.Input.Spatial.SpatialPointerPose`. The Mixed Reality OpenXR plugin can work with non-UWP app (editor or standalone).

Comment: Thanks, this works much better. Is there anyway to get a timestamp from the device using OpenXR? Otherwise, I can just get the current Unix time at the remote server, which doesn't correctly reflect the gaze sample time because of the rendering and network delays.

Comment: Saw your answer on timestamps for MRTK case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71952196/accessing-eye-gaze-timestamp-from-hololens-2-in-unity-for-holographic-remoting), just wondering if OpenXR provides access to the timing on device.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to get eye gaze data at a fixed rate from a non-UWP app (editor or standalone) would be using [Mixed Reality OpenXR Plugin](https://github.com/microsoft/OpenXR-Unity-MixedReality-Samples). The code would be similar to [FollowEyeGaze.cs](https://github.com/microsoft/OpenXR-Unity-MixedReality-Samples/blob/main/BasicSample/Assets/Interaction/Scripts/FollowEyeGaze.cs). But instead of using "Update()" method, we can use a timer to get the data at a fixed rate.

While using Unity OpenXR Plugin, we can use the [InputDevice.TryGetFeatureUsages](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/XR.InputDevice.TryGetFeatureUsages.html) method to get a list of every [InputFeatureUsage](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/XR.InputFeatureUsage.html) that a device provides. For the EyeTracking device, there is no time related feature usage. So, OpenXR Plugin also can't provide the eye gaze sample timestamp.

Comment: Just a note: This works inside the `Update` function but not inside a timer, with fixed rate, somehow.

Comment: What do you mean "not work inside a timer"? Could you please share more details?

Comment: I tried to create a `Timer` object like `fetchDataTimer = new Timer(fetchInterval)` where `fetchInterval` = 10 ms, for instance, and run a function after each interval:  `fetchDataTimer.Elapsed += CheckForEyeData`. Then I started the timer, but I don't get any data if I run the OpenXR plugin function `InputDevice.TryGetFeatureUsages` inside the timer function `CheckForEyeData`. It does work though, if I run the same code inside the `Update()` function. I know that the timer code works because I can run other stuff in that, just the gaze fetching part doesn't work.

Comment: I didn't test with `System.Timers.Timer`. As it's designed for use with worker threads in a multithreaded environment and can move among threads, Accessing Unity object within it may create unpredictable effects. I'm using Unity Coroutine to implement the timer and it works.