# Accessing eye gaze timestamp from HoloLens 2 in Unity (for Holographic Remoting)

Tags: hololens, mrtk, eye-tracking

I'm trying to get the timestamps of the eye gaze data from HoloLens 2 using `eyeGazeProvider.Timestamp`. According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.mixedreality.toolkit.input.imixedrealityeyegazeprovider?view=mixed-reality-toolkit-unity-2020-dotnet-2.7.0), this should return the time when "the signal was last updated". However, if I use this in the context of Holographic Remoting, it returns the time when the frame is rendered in Unity, which of course happens in the remote server and does not reflect the actual timing of the eye gaze sample. For a UWP app deployed in HL2, it is possible to get pretty accurate timings with `eyeGazeProvider.Timestamp` though (~33ms apart due to 30Hz eyetracker frequency).

Is there a way to get the correct timestamps using Holographic Remoting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to get the eye gaze sample timestamp with using `EyeGazeProvider`. As we can see from [the source code](https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/blob/main/Assets/MRTK/Providers/OpenXR/Scripts/OpenXREyeGazeDataProvider.cs#L189), the `Timestamp` is always set to the time when the eye tracking data is retrieved.